# Find functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to[0,1]$ such that: $\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{f(x)^2}{f(2 x)}=1$

Tags: calculus, limits, functional-equations

Find functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to[0,1]$ that satisfy: $$\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{f(x)^2}{f(2 x)}=1,$$
$$f'(x)\leq 0 \, \forall x,$$
and
$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x)=0.$$
$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x)=1.$$
I tried to find one without success.

Comment: I think $(\arctan(-x)+\pi/2)/\pi$ satisfies the last 3 requirements. Not sure of the 1st one.

Comment: $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}(1-\tanh (ax)), a>0$

Comment: No, seems my function does not satisfy the 1st condition. Seems it has a limit of 0 there.

Comment: Do you really need to find _all_ such functions? That doesn't look feasible to me $-$ there are zillions of functions that satisfy the last three requirements, and the first requirement only affects the behaviour as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: Removed the "all".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the constructions above we can see that any function of the form
$$\frac{1}{a^{cx}+1}$$
for $a>0$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$ will work. It would appear that you want some type of generalization of a sigmoid function (just a guess). Perhaps Gompertz functions might be a good thing to look at.

Answer (score 7):

An example is $$f(x)=e^{-x-\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$

HOW DID I FIND THIS?

1. The first requirement is satisfied by functions like $e^{\alpha x}$, so I thought that looking at a possible logarithm of $f$ would have been a good idea. So we need that $\log f$ has a negative asymptote at $+ \infty$
2. Fourth conditions say that $\log f$ must have an horizontal asymptote at $- \infty$, tending to $0$
3. So, I thought that an hyperbola would work. Such an hyperbola is for example
   $$y(y+2x)-1=0$$, which gives you $$y=-x-\sqrt{x^2+1}$$ for $y > 0$.

EDIT: I just found another simpler one: $$f(x) = \frac{1}{e^x+1}$$

Comment: Excellent!. Seems it also satisfies $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f[x]^n}{f[n x]}=1, n>1$

Comment: @Nero You are right. It seems that we have found a pretty nice function, then.

Comment: I would add that "find ALL functions satisfying etc" is quite hard. Once you find one of them, you can slightly modify it (using a perturbation) to find infintely many other ones. So, I think that finiding one is enough for us.

Comment: Your function resembles the tanh used @gammatester since $\frac{1}{2} \left(1-\tanh \left(\frac{\kappa  x}{\pi }\right)\right)$=$\frac{1}{e^{\frac{2 \kappa  x}{\pi }}+1}$

Answer (score 2):

All functions $$f_a(x) = \frac{1}{2}\left(1-\tanh(ax)\right),  a> 0$$
solve your requirements. Since $a$ is just a rescaling, we need only show this
for $a=1$. Let  $f(x) = f_a(x) = f_1(x)$. The derivative is $f'(x) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\tanh(x)^2 - 1\right) \le 0$
and 
$$\frac{f(x)^2}{f(2x)}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{2\cosh(x)^2-1}{\cosh(x)^2}
= 1- \frac{1}{2\cosh(x)^2} < 1
$$
with a limit $1$ for $x\rightarrow \infty$.
The limits of $f(x)$ for $x\rightarrow \pm \infty$ are trivial.

Comment: You can also write the function $\frac{1}{e^{2 a  x}+1}$

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

$f(x) = \frac{1}{1+\text{exp}(x)}$?